# Extracting all columns containing a list of terms

Tags: awk, grep

I have a data file (`data.txt`) with ~320 rows and ~1800 columns (1.9 MB), and I need to extract certain columns out (for all rows). The general layout of `data.txt` is as follows:

```
 ID           Adipocyte - breast, donor2.CNhs11969.11327-117E4   ....
HGNC:8888                        0                               .... 
HGNC:9999                     123.92                             ....
HGNC:1000                      9.31                              ....
```

I have a list of the columns I need to extract (in a file `list.txt`), but this list is made up of only the CNhsXXXXX identifier in the column term (i.e. for the above example, the list would only contain **CNhs11969**, not the whole term *Adipocyte - breast, donor2.CNhs11969.11327-117E4*).

I've used grep for a list of rows before, but have not for columns. I had a look around but could not find a way to grep multiple columns with multiple terms. I'm very new to unix (I'm a biologist, little experience in computing), so I'm unsure if grep can do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: My sample output would be only ~850 of the ~1800 columns (only those containing the terms in my `list.txt` file). Example: If my list contained only CNhs5006 and CNhs7021, I would only want columns containing those terms in the header. Example of the `data.txt`:

```
ID        XXXCNhs5006XXX   XXXCNhs6025XXX   XXXCNhs7021XXX   XXXCNhs8095XXX
HGNC:1111     1.23                 1.53             9.21            0
HGNC:2222     1.95                73.92               0           123.29
```

Example of the desired output:

```
ID         XXXCNhs5006XXX   XXXCNhs7021
HGNC:1111          1.23          9.21
HGNC:2222          1.95           0
```

My `list.txt` is just a simple list of terms (1 column, ~850 rows, each row containing 1 search term). Example:

`CNhs1111
CNhs2222
CNhs3333
CNhs4444`

Comment: I don't understand what would you want to extract ? If you can post your sample output that would be nice to us

Comment: Of the ~1800 columns, I would want only ~850 containing the terms in my `list.txt` file.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a file containing _column names_ and want to extract the corresponding columns from a data file on the basis of the column names in the header line. If so, `grep` can't do that, `awk` can. But it is unclear how to identify the columns. Please elaborate.

Comment: what `list.txt` contains ? rather than extending conversation here, please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/295301/edit) your post and show it to others

Comment: My post is now updated for my desired output.

Comment: is your `CNhs5006` and `CNhs7021` will be fixed column position ? you didn't post sample of `list.txt` yet

Comment: @MichaelVehrs I thought grep wouldn't be able to do so, thanks for your response. The columns in `data.txt` contain a string that within it contains what I am searching for. For example, the column headers in `data.txt` are "Adipose tissue - donor 1.CNhs9999.abc-asd", BUT my list of search terms only contains the "CNhs9999" part of the header and not the rest (i.e. the prefix "adipose tissue - donor 1, or the suffix ".abc-asd")

Comment: @Rahul Updated my original post to show the layout. It is just a simple list (1 column with ~850 rows, each row containing 1 term that being my search term).

Comment: So, how are the column names in the header line delimited? It seems that the names contain blanks.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs The column names in the header are tab delimited (since yes there are spaces/blanks in the column names). Is that an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose OP can do the follows:

1. Read header `data.txt` and convert columns into rows
2. `Grep` the rows to obtain numbers to match `list.txt`
3. Pass `data.txt` through the `cut`

If columns are tab delimited the script can be:

```
cut -f 1,$(
    head -n1 data.txt |
    tr '\t' '\n' |
    grep -nf list.txt |
    sed ':a;$!N;s/:[^\n]*\n/,/;ta;s/:.*//'
) data.txt
```

Comment: it works great! Thanks Costas

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
awk  -F'\t' -f script.awk column.names data
```

where `script.awk` is:

```
NR == FNR { columns[NR] = $0; next }
NR > FNR && FNR == 1 {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < NR; j++) {
            if ($i ~ columns[j]) {
                selected[i] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (i in selected) printf $i "\t";
    }
    print "";
}
```

@Costas's approach is neat. However, I think it could be slightly simplified:

```
head -n1 data | tr '\t' '\n' | grep -nf column.names | cut -f1 -d: \
  | paste -sd, | xargs -I{} cut -f {} data
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is just returning a blank document (~1400 lines, just nothing there). I tried recreating the list file and re-duplicating the data.txt file from its copy but still no luck, so I don't believe it's a dos line ending problem.